# Slicing a tensor with indices of tensor

Tags: tensorflow

In a mini_batch, I have a hidden word embedding tensor that is `h`, shape(h) is (?, 300), and an attention words embedding tensor `attention_words`, where shape(attention_words) is (?, num, 300). Now I want to find the closest word in B to each word in A. In this condition, I use the cosine distance to measure, as

```
    normed_attention_words = tf.nn.l2_normalize(attention_words, dim=2)
    normed_hidden = tf.nn.l2_normalize(h, dim=1) 

    normed_hidden = tf.expand_dims(normed_hidden, 1) # (?,1,300)

    #num is the number of attention words
    normed_hidden = tf.tile(normed_hidden, [1, num, 1]) #(?,num,300)

    cosine_similarity = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(normed_attention_words, normed_hidden), 2)

    closest_words = tf.argmax(cosine_similarity, 1)
```

Hence, shape(closest_words) is (?,). I want to utilize the tensor `closest_words` as the index to slice original `attention_words`. I have tried many times but failed (especially tf.gather_nd, cause the Gradient for gather_nd is not implemented). So in this condition, how to solve this problem?

Comment: `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`